# Excel - Wildcard match with multiple criteria?

Tags: sql, excel, database

I have a database spreadsheet where I need to pull key information from the master data. As you can see in the below screenshots, the goal is to return the "Part Number" and the only data I can match with are the "Kenn" and the "Part Code", "Kenn" can be directly matched with "KENN No" from the master data and the part code is the first 6 digits of the "Part Number", so I am thinking of using the wildcard or LEFT function. I have tried the following formula but it did not work for me, please advise. Many thanks.

Screenshots:

**Main Sheet**

[image: Main Sheet]

**Master Data (Report_PC_Data)**

[image: Master Data (Report_PC_Data)]

Cross posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/excel-wildcard-match-with-multiple-criteria.1158059/

Comment: I'd use the `FILTER` function (available in Excel O365)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I do not have Excel O365.

Comment: In that case you can use the `AGGREGATE` function to figure out the row number; then `INDEX` to return what you need from that row. There are examples of that approach on this forum. Post back with your attempts, and questions.